# Update Database using Html Form Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to edit the profile of the user but I'm getting this error:

`ErrorException in editController.php line 144: Creating default object from empty value`

This is my edit.blade.php

```
                    <blockquote>
                    <p>You could edit your profile here.</p>
                    </blockquote>

                <table width="80%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lname" value='{{ $user -> lname}}' size="20"><br>
                             {{ ($errors->has('lname')) ? $errors->first('lname') : '' }} <br> </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fname" value='{{ $user -> fname}}' size="20"><br>
                             {{ ($errors->has('fname1')) ? $errors->first('fname') : '' }} <br> </td>               
                    </tr>  

                    <tr>
                        <td>Middle Name: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="mname" value='{{ $user -> mname}}' size="20"><br>
                             {{ ($errors->has('mname')) ? $errors->first('mname') : '' }} <br> </td>                
                    </tr>             

                    <tr>
                        <td>Email Address: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" value='{{ $user -> email}}' size="20">
                        <br> {{ ($errors->has('email')) ? $errors->first('email') : '' }} <br> </td>               
                    </tr>

                    <tr>                    
                        <td>

                       <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update Profile" name = "submit" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 7px;">
                       <a href="/home" class="btn btn-default" role="button" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 7px;">Back</a>

                       </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
```

This is my editController

```
public function index()

{

     $user = Auth::user();
    return view('user/profile', array('user' => $user));
}

    public function edit(){
        //$user = User::find($id);
         $user = Auth::user();
        // display the article to single page
       return view('user/editProfile', array('user' => $user));

    }

   public function update()
    {

        // Get the status
            $user = Auth::user();

           $userf->fname = Input::get('fname');
           $userm->mname = Input::get('mname');
           $userl->lname = Input::get('lname');
           $usere->email = Input::get('email');

           $sql = "UPDATE users SET fname= ? mname= ? lname = ? email = ? WHERE id= ?";
           DB::update($sql, array($userf, $userm, $userl, $usere , $user));

            return Redirect::to('/home');

    }
```

This is my routes

```
Route::get('/home', 'editController@index');
Route::get('/editProfile', 'editController@edit');
Route::post('/updating', 'editController@update');
```

Could you help me found out why I'm getting this error? Thanks for the help

Comment: When is the error happening? When you show the edit view? When you submit the edit form? And can you post the exact content of line 144 from your Controller?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mentioned that. It was during submit the edit form.

Comment: I don't see that you declare $userf,$userm,$userl,$usere as object anywhere.

Comment: Usually this is caused by an empty value in your db record. Are there any null or empty values? You need to check that, and make sure they have a value. Wrap an '@if(! empty($user))' block to your value attribute to be safe.

Comment: Sorry I think I was wrong just now. You should use $request->user() to get the user.

Answer (score 0):

So as I can see, the problem is that you are using $userf,$userm,$userl,$usere as object without declaring first these variables like object so when you do `$userf->fname` you get the error `Creating default object from empty value`.

I think that you only need yo use $user object to asign the new properties and save it to database.

So you can do

```
$user->fname = Input::get('fname');
$user->mname = Input::get('mname');
$user->lname = Input::get('lname');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
```

And then you can use Laravel ORM to save the data `$user->save();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use $request->user() to return an instance of the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my controller and it worked:
here's what I did:

```
public function update()
{

    // Get the status
       $user = Auth::user();

       $userf = Input::get('fname');
       $userm = Input::get('mname');
       $userl = Input::get('lname');
       $usere = Input::get('email');

       $save = DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $user->id)
                ->update(array('fname' => $userf, 'mname'=>$userm, 'lname'=>$userl,'email'=>$usere));

       return redirect('/home');
```